# QuickBooks integration , got error

Tags: quickbooks

i am trying to add record to QuickBooks with my application but got an error

ERROR:
Could not load file or assembly 'Interop.QBFC13Lib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I have added QBC13Lib namespace and included qbFC13lic in reference. it Build Fine but when I click on button to add record to QuickBooks, gets that error.

CODE
 QBSessionManager sessionManager = new QBSessionManager();
            sessionManager.OpenConnection("appID", "Create Vendor");

```
        sessionManager.BeginSession("", ENOpenMode.omDontCare);  //1: location  2: mode
       IMsgSetRequest messageSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest("US", 7, 0);

       //  IMsgSetRequest messageSet = sessionManager.CreateMsgSetRequest();
        IVendorAdd vendorAddRequest = messageSet.AppendVendorAddRq();

        vendorAddRequest.Name.SetValue("ACME, Inc");
        vendorAddRequest.CompanyName.SetValue("ACME, Inc");
        vendorAddRequest.VendorAddress.Addr1.SetValue("123 Some St");
        vendorAddRequest.VendorAddress.City.SetValue("Somecity");
        vendorAddRequest.VendorAddress.State.SetValue("ST");
        vendorAddRequest.VendorAddress.PostalCode.SetValue("12345");

        IMsgSetResponse responseSet = sessionManager.DoRequests(messageSet);
        sessionManager.EndSession();
        sessionManager.CloseConnection();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the QB SDK in your PC and set a reference to the library in you project.  Make sure that the QuickBooks application is running with the appropriate company file open.  Also, login as Admin as you will need to grant permission to the program trying to access QuickBooks for the first time.

Comment: Then you shouldn't post an answer unless it's an actual answer.